# Google developer screenshot (graphic assets) error image not valid

Tags: upload, screenshot, developer-tools

Trying to upload any graphics such as screenshot, icon, Feature graphic and I keep having the same error from from Google while my picture have the right spec.
message is "Upload Error" "You need to check that your screenshot image is valid valid" or "You need to fix your feature graphic is valid"

Anyone has the same error or any clue?

I've even used another graphic from another app published and it still dont want it anymore. 
I've also deleted my app and create a new one in the Dev account. Same issue. I'm desperate.

Comment: The same here. Maybe google has an issue right now on its console

Comment: I also have this problem, every image I try to upload gives me image not valid error. Doesn't mather if its screenshots, icon or feature graphics i try to upload.

Comment: I've reported the Bug to Google.... I'm so upset! I need to publish it ASAP. I've tried everything.  Delete the app and start from scratch, ask a colleague in another country to try, try in another Browser. All graphic assets can't be uploaded

Comment: Anyone know a way to join by chat Google?

Comment: Any update? Here it isn't working for some of our guys...

Answer (score 2):

I have the same error. Try with another browser. Firefox works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For me a new window in incognito mode works!

Answer (score 1):

Update: It seems to be working now. I was facing the same problem just an hour ago and now i'm able to upload screenshots