# Error on uploading apk created with app inventor 2

Tags: google-play, developer-console

I just created an app with App Inventor 2. I clicked on Build and then saved it on Computer. Then uploaded the .apk on my google developer console account.

But when the upload completes, it says:

```
Upload failed
Check the symbol in your apk-file. It is not valid
```

German Original: "Hochladen fehlgeschlagen
Überprüfe das Symbol in deiner APK-Datei. Es ist nicht gültig."

Comment: I am no expert here. But you should edit the TAGs of this question. 'upload' is too broad here, and does not bring android experts to this question. Instead you can tag the app-inventor maybe. and "app-store" is the name of the platform of Apple company for iphone apps! Google's platform is called "Google play".

Answer (score 0):

Same here! It seems there is a bug in Google Developer Console right now, hope they'll fix it soon. 
Check this question too: [Google developer screenshot (graphic assets) error image not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804389/google-developer-screenshot-graphic-assets-error-image-not-valid)